# Unable to access local variable via a function call through ssh

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

This the code I,m trying to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -a

err_report() {
    echo "Error on line $1"
}

trap 'err_report $LINENO' ERR

IFS=$'\n'

value=($(cat builds.txt))

prevBuild=${value[0]}
prevBuildDir=$prevBuild
currentBuild=${value[1]}
currentBuildDir=$currentBuild

splitPrevBuild=(${prevBuild//./$'\n'})
splitcurrentBuild=(${currentBuild//./$'\n'})

prevBuildSR=${splitPrevBuild[2]}
prevBuildHF=${splitPrevBuild[3]}
prevBuildNum=${splitPrevBuild[4]}
currentBuildSR=${splitcurrentBuild[2]}
currentBuildHF=${splitcurrentBuild[3]}
currentBuildNum=${splitcurrentBuild[4]}

function change {
    cd ~/InstallationFiles/${currentBuildSR}/${currentBuildDir}/${currentBuild}extracted
}

change
pwd
ssh -T atao52@kvs-in-hsglap17.in.kronos.com <<-EOF
$(typeset -f)
change
pwd
echo hi
exit
EOF
```

How to access the variables as currently, it says
cd: /home/atao52/InstallationFiles///extracted: No such file or directory

Comment: `typeset -f` only prints the function definitions, not the variables. How do you expect the remote machine to get the variables from the client?

Comment: Is there any way to get the remote machine to access the variables from the client when inside a function? Coz I'm able to access the variables if they aren't contained in a function.

Comment: Use `typeset` instead of `typeset -f`. But this will send *all* your local environment variables to the server, not just the ones in the script.